# How to deploy my own computer as a web server?

Tags: webserver, deployment

How can I have a large bandwidth,and how can I have a static IP address?

Answer (score 1):

This info is easily available on the web.  Talk to your ISP about a static IP and the amount of bandwidth you are looking for.  Check to see if fiber is available in your area.

I run Ubuntu Server and host a couple of sites.  Below is a getting started with Ubuntu Server link.  Read everything you can and talk to someone in the business.  Usually we are glad to help.

[here](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-9.04-ispconfig-2)

EDIT: 9.04 is an older version, but the info still applies.  Get the latest version [here](http://www.ubuntu.com).

EDIT:  Additionally, I use [Putty](http://www.putty.org/) to connect to and administer my server.  I have learned more in the last year from running this sever than I ever expected.  If this is just a home/personal site have fun with it (the server)!

Answer (score 0):

You need three things.

Static IP from your ISP
Bandwidth from your ISP
Server for hosting websites (Windows, Linux/Apache, other)

Some ISP's actually "forbid" hosting public websites... you can usually still get away with it, but i'm not advocating it ;-)

Also, as a "hack" if you don't have a Windows Server license but you want to run IIS, just grab a copy of XP Pro, Vista Business, Win7 Pro, etc... those OS's allow for a SINGLE website in IIS.